# SQL Adapter Fill - Duplicate Column

Tags: c#

I'm using SqlDataAdapter.Fill to retrieve data from a query that has 2 columns like Column and COLUMN.  Unforunately, the second column is inserted in the table as Column_1.  I've ran this quick test and it seems that datatable is capable of case sensitive names but adapter.fill is not providing me with them.  Is there any way to force adapter.fill to do so?

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("NUMBER", typeof(int));


    table.Rows.Add(123, 123);

    foreach(var column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52xzw8tf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for DataColumnCollection from .NET 2.0 - 4.5, the Add method is case-insensitive and is *supposed* to throw a DuplicateNameException in this scenario.

From the Exceptions section for `DuplicateNameException`:

> The collection already has a column with the specified name. (The
>   comparison is not case-sensitive.)

I'm unsure why it is not throwing the documented exception, but the documentation coupled with the SqlDataAdapter behavior you're seeing would suggest that it is not intended for what you are attempting.